# JQuery mouseover and click event

Tags: jquery

I have a menu list, as I scroll over the menu list the related divs are shown or hidden. This works fine with the following:

```
$('.ov_menu li').mouseover(function(){
        var div_show = ($(this).parent().attr('href'));

        $('.homepage_display').hide();
        $(div_show).show();
        $('.ov_menu li').css('background-color','#ffffff')
        $(this).css('background-color','#cceffc');

        return false;
});
```

What is the most efficient way to display the relevant div when I click on the menu item, without having to type out the above code again (but using the click event rather than the mouseover event).

Markup:

```
<div class="ov_menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#new"><li>Create New Check</li></a>
            <a href="#in_progress"><li>In Progress Checks</li></a>
            <a href="#completed"><li>Completed Checks</li></a>
            <a href="#archived"><li>Archived Checks</li></a>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="homepage_display" id="new">
Content
</div>

<div class="homepage_display" id="in_progress">
Content
</div>

<div class="homepage_display" id="completed">
Content
</div>

<div class="homepage_display" id="archived">
Content
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract it out to use a named function.

```
function ShowSomething() {
    var div_show = ($(this).parent().attr('href'));

    $('.homepage_display').hide();
    $(div_show).show();
    $('.ov_menu li').css('background-color', '#ffffff')
    $(this).css('background-color', '#cceffc');

    return false;
}

$('.ov_menu li').mouseover(ShowSomething);
//or
$('.ov_menu li').click(ShowSomething);
```

**[Simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/ZNQnM/)**

Comment: Thanks Mark,  sometimes the answer is so simple it stares me in the face.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help `:)`